# How to Allow From IP Address, Serve 404 Otherwise?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip, http-status-code-404

I am looking to deny access to my /wp-admin/ folder to everyone but specific IP addresses. For everyone else, the page should serve a 404 error. Here's what I'm working with thus far:

```
    # ALLOW USER BY IP
    <Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 168.162.1.3
    RedirectMatch 404 ".*"    
    </Limit>
```

I believe I'm close, but the problem is that a 404 error is not served, instead it creates a redirect loop. This would obviously be taxing on my server for no reason. So how then, can a simply serve a 404 error to everyone but these specific IP addresses and also deny them access to the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea. I'm curious as to why you're so keen on a 404 error as opposed to a 403! I guess you could be trying to mask WordPress but then you'll have to mask all the references to wp-content on the frontend too.

Anyway, let's get on with this. In order to do this, do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=8.8.8.8 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteRule ^wp-admin($|/) - [L,R=404]
```

Set 8.8.8.8 to your real IP Address. You can add additional OR conditions to whitelist other IPs the same way I did with localhost (127.0.0.1).

You will need to be using Apache 2.1.1 or above because we are using the R=404 flag.

Comment: Thanks for the help! What would the advantage be to using a 403 instead?

Comment: It is a more appropriate error message, it is a Forbidden message instead of a not found error. I suppose a not found error can better help mask the WordPress install as it could confuse the attacker (maybe lead them to think you've completely renamed the wp-login.php and wp-admin paths). If you've found the answer useful please accept it (click the empty tick). Thanks!

Comment: Travis, if you are happy with the answer, can you please click the empty tick underneath the vote buttons in order to accept it and mark the question as resolved? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work correctly for me. I think we're close, but not quite there.

Comment: I see, have you adjusted the IP address from 8.8.8.8 to the IP you were looking to whitelist? I'll try it out locally and get back with my findings.

Comment: @mjsa, you want to join those "not" conditions with "and", which is implicit in a list of RewriteCond statements. As written, it will always be true:  it's either not 8.8.8.8 `[OR]` it's not 127.0.0.1. Also, most other examples escape the each period with a backslash; I'm not clear if that's mandatory in IP addresses.